# How can i check if the value exists and return different values depending on the answer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, case, exists

First let me explain the Query im using at the moment.

As an example this query returns the value '357 kg':

```
SELECT TOP 1 
     CONCAT(POCI.Value,' kg')
FROM 
     ProductionOrder PO
          LEFT JOIN Product P ON P.ProductionOrderId = PO.ProductionOrderId
          LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfiguration POC ON POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = PO.ProductionOrderConfigurationId 
          LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfigurationItem POCI ON POCI.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId
WHERE 
     P.ProductId = #ProductId# AND POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA'
```

The problem is that sometimes the POCI.Name (C_VIKTA) doesnt exists in the records, so its value (POCI.Value) doesnt get returned.
So i want the following logic to work, and i know that it can be solved with an CASE and EXISTS, but i just dont get that to work..

The result I want is that IF the POCI.Value exists return CONCAT(POCI.Value,' kg') ELSE return 'N/A'.  Anyone got any idea on how to solve this?

Let me know if theres something else u need to know in order to help me out!

BR,

Mik

Comment: `Order by` plays an important role when using `Top`:)

Comment: @LONG good point, although maybe in this case it's known that it would be the same repeating value and the order is irrelevant, I've run into that sometimes

Comment: @AnthonyHancock, yeah, maybe op has a clustered index so the result are consistent every time he runs xD

Comment: Order by doesnt matter, it can only be 1 record, the TOP 1 is there because it was copied from another query at some point, but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @LONG Would you be so kind as to point me to a reference that explains the _guaranteed_ order of results from four joined tables that have a clustered index somewhere? My feeble understanding is that without an `order by` clause there is no guarantee that the order won't change with new index statistics, a software patch, an extra processor core, ... . (For a tale of something that worked consistently in testing: [The "Bug" Heard 'Round the World](https://cs162.eecs.berkeley.edu/static/readings/garman_bug_81.pdf).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you move `AND POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA'` from where clause to your left join as shown below

```
SELECT TOP 1 
     case when POCI.Value is not null then CONCAT(POCI.Value,' kg') else '' end
FROM 
     ProductionOrder PO
          LEFT JOIN Product P ON P.ProductionOrderId = PO.ProductionOrderId
          LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfiguration POC ON POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = PO.ProductionOrderConfigurationId 
          LEFT JOIN ProductionOrderConfigurationItem POCI ON POCI.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId AND POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA'
WHERE 
     P.ProductId = #ProductId#
```

Comment: Thank you Stivan, that worked out very well. Exactly what i was looking for! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to drop CONCAT which handles nulls and then rely on is null. So your single select column would be

```
SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(POCI.Value+' kg','N\A')
```

This way you would get a null for the first argument if POCI.Value is null and therefore return 'N\A'

Comment: As @Stivan mentioned in his answer, you would definitely have to move the name check out of the where clause or you won't return anything when the name doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

this `WHERE POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA'` breaks the left join
so move it up into the left join or make them all regular joins

if it only return one row then drop the top

`+` behaves different than concat

```
SELECT ISNULL(POCI.Value +' kg','N\A')
FROM ProductionOrder PO
JOIN Product P 
       ON P.ProductionOrderId = PO.ProductionOrderId
JOIN ProductionOrderConfiguration POC 
       ON POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId  = PO.ProductionOrderConfigurationId 
JOIN ProductionOrderConfigurationItem POCI 
       ON POCI.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = POC.ProductionOrderConfigurationId           
WHERE POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA' 
  AND P.ProductId = #ProductId#
```

why do you need `ProductionOrderConfiguration POC` ?

```
SELECT ISNULL(POCI.Value +' kg','N\A')
    FROM ProductionOrder PO
    JOIN Product P 
           ON P.ProductionOrderId = PO.ProductionOrderId
    JOIN ProductionOrderConfigurationItem POCI 
           ON POCI.ProductionOrderConfigurationId = PO.ProductionOrderConfigurationId           
    WHERE POCI.Name = 'C_VIKTA' 
      AND P.ProductId = #ProductId#
```